# Wpf-Application looks different on windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, listbox, windows-10

I created WPF application with a listbox which contains checkboxes(checklistbox) for windows7. I installed the same application on windows 10 and the GUI looks very different. On **Windows 7** the checklistbox in the **same line**. But on **windows 10** the **box** is **higher** and the text is lower (see picture please)

[image]

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbSchlagwoerter" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="300" MaxHeight="390" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="3" Margin="5,5,5,5">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <CheckBox Margin="5,2" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </CheckBox>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: `<CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center"` Try this or you can set ContentPresenter  VerticaltAlignment="Center"

Comment: it works with VerticalContentAlignment, Thank you so much Avinash :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the VerticalContentAlignment to Center.

`<CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center"`